# Adding Text on Image

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I am trying to add some text on top of a photo take by the camera, and here is the method I am using, but unfortunately I either get a closedStream error, or that there is cross-thread access when I try use the dispatcher. Could someone please explain me what is going wrong?

```
    void cam_CaptureImageAvailable(object sender, Microsoft.Devices.ContentReadyEventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
        string fileName = dt.Year.ToString() + dt.Month.ToString() + dt.Day.ToString() + dt.Hour.ToString() + dt.Minute.ToString() + dt.Second.ToString() + ".jpg";

        try
        {  
            // Save picture to the library camera roll.
            library.SavePictureToCameraRoll(fileName, e.ImageStream);

            // Set the position of the stream back to start
            e.ImageStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                // load photo to writable bitmap 
                WriteableBitmap writeableBitmap = PictureDecoder.DecodeJpeg(e.ImageStream);
                writeableBitmap.Invalidate();
                var renderText = new TextBlock
                {
                    Text = "Hello World",
                    FontSize = 72,
                    Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White),
                    FontWeight = FontWeights.Black,
                    Width = 500,
                    Height = 100
                };

                writeableBitmap.Render(renderText, new TranslateTransform() { X = 100, Y = 300 });
                writeableBitmap.Invalidate();

                using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    writeableBitmap.SaveJpeg(ms, 1024, 768, 0, 100);
                    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                    library.SavePicture("x" + fileName, ms);
                }

                // e.ImageStream.Close();
            });

            // Save picture as JPEG to isolated storage.
            using (IsolatedStorageFile isStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                using (IsolatedStorageFileStream targetStream = isStore.OpenFile(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
                {
                    // Initialize the buffer for 4KB disk pages.
                    byte[] readBuffer = new byte[4096];
                    int bytesRead = -1;

                    // Copy the image to isolated storage. 
                    while ((bytesRead = e.ImageStream.Read(readBuffer, 0, readBuffer.Length)) > 0)
                    {
                        targetStream.Write(readBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            // Close image stream
            e.ImageStream.Close();
        }
    }
```

With the code above I get the following error: Cannot access a closed Stream.

If i remove the Dispatcher, I get this error: Invalid cross-thread access.

Thanks.

Comment: Without the dispatcher, on which line do you get the 'invalid cross-thread access' error?

Comment: this line: WriteableBitmap writeableBitmap = PictureDecoder.DecodeJpeg(e.ImageStream);

Answer (score 0):

place ui less code outside dispatcher scope.

or save your e.ImageStream to other stream can be gotted in dispatcher scope.

Comment: "or save your e.ImageStream to other stream can be gotted in dispatcher scope." How would I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

First, what is occurring?

`Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` postpones your code and tells the UI thread to execute it whenever it's available. Therefore, your `e.ImageStream.Close();` line is executed before the code inside of the `BeginInvoke`. So when you're trying to read the contents of the stream, it's already closed.

Two ways to solve that:

1. Remove the `e.ImageStream.Close();` from the `finally` block. But I don't know if the stream will remain open anyway.
2. If 1. doesn't work, copy the contents of the stream to a `MemoryStream`, then use this stream to create the `WriteableBitmap`:

   ```
   var stream = new MemoryStream();
   e.ImageStream.CopyTo(stream);
   ```

In both case, don't forget to close the stream when you're done creating the `WriteableBitmap`.